# GroupJoin with top selection on join table using Linq for Entities lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a table with a many->many relationship although not classified as such in the database schema.

I have the following SQL that I would like to replicate with equivalent lambdas.

```
SELECT S1.ServiceId, S1.ServiceDate, S1.TrainNumber, S1.SourceMessageRef, 

S2.SourceMessageRef, S1.Created, S2.Created, S1.vehicles, S1.grossWeight, S1.NettWeight, S1.Tare, S1.Nominal, S2.ConsignmentNoteNum, S2.NumOfWagons, S2.GrossWeight, S2.NettWeight, S2.NominalTonnes
FROM (select c.ServiceId, c.ServiceDate, c.TrainNumber, c.SourceMessageRef, c.Created, COUNT(1) as vehicles, SUM(c.GrossWeight) AS GrossWeight, SUM(c.NettWeight) as NettWeight, sum(c.TareWeight) as Tare, sum(c.NominalWeight) as Nominal
        from [Staging].[Consists] c
        GROUP BY [ServiceId],[ServiceDate],[TrainNumber],[SourceMessageRef],[Created]
        ) AS S1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT c.Created, c.SourceMessageRef, c.ServiceId, 
                        c.ServiceDate, c.ConsignmentNoteNum, c.GrossWeight, 
                        c.NettWeight, c.NominalTonnes, c.NumOfWagons,
                        row_number() over (partition by c.ServiceId, c.ServiceDate order by c.Created DESC) as rn
                   FROM [Staging].[Consignment] c ) S2 
        ON S2.ServiceId = S1.ServiceId AND S2.ServiceDate = S1.ServiceDate AND S2.rn = 1
ORDER BY S2.ServiceDate DESC, S1.Created DESC, S2.SourceMessageRef DESC, S1.SourceMessageRef DESC
```

So far the best I can achieve is :

```
    var consists = db.Consists
        .GroupBy(c => new { c.ServiceId, c.ServiceDate, c.SourceMessageRef })
        .GroupJoin(db.Consignments,
            a => new { a.Key.ServiceId, a.Key.ServiceDate },
            b => new { b.ServiceId, b.ServiceDate },
            (a, b) => new ConsistOverviewDto() 
                {
                    ServiceId = a.Key.ServiceId,
                    ServiceDate = a.Key.ServiceDate,
                    TrainNumber = a.FirstOrDefault().TrainNumber,
                    ConsistVehicleCount = a.Count(),
                    ConsistGrossWeight = a.Sum(a1 => a1.GrossWeight ?? 0m),
                    ConsistNettWeight = a.Sum(a1 => a1.NettWeight ?? 0m),
                    ConsistTareWeight = a.Sum(a1 => a1.TareWeight ?? 0m),
                    ConsistNominalWeight = a.Sum(a1 => a1.NominalWeight ?? 0),

                    ConsignmentVehicleCount = b.Count(),
                    ConsignmentGrossWeight = b.Sum(b1 => b1.GrossWeight ?? 0m),
                    ConsigmentNettWeight = b.Sum(b1 => b1.NettWeight ?? 0m),
                    ConsignmentNominalWeight = b.Sum(b1 => b1.NominalTonnes ?? 0)
                })
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.ServiceDate);
```

This doesn't seem to come very close, particularly the concept of only wanting to match the first outer join entry if any present.

Can someone assist in demonstrating the lambda required to achieve the functionality similiar to the SQL attached.